# Missing columns in DB table when attempting to remove unused tokens

Tags: schema, token, wso2-identity-server

We are running 5.4.0 of WSO2 Identity Server and have been getting slow query warnings on the IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table. We investigated several causes and came across this article in the WSO2 documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Removing+Unused+Tokens+from+the+Database

We noticed, however, that we had columns referenced in the proc that do not exist in the table: CONSUMER_KEY and TOKEN_SCOPE.  I have been searching the WSO2 Git repo looking for schemas that might account for the difference in the table but I can't find any.  Is anyone familiar with WSO2 IS and can tell us why these particular columns are missing from the table?  Is it version related?  We could modify the proc to use different column names but this finding has made me question the integrity of WSO2 components we have installed (actually a third party developed the solution).  Just looking for a rational explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an identified DOC issue[1][2]. For your requirement please refer to this.[3] or [4].

[1].https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5103
[2].https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5102
[3].https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/blob/master/scripts/token-cleanup-scripts/mysql.sql
[4].https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/features/identity-core/org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.server.feature/resources/dbscripts/stored-procedures/mysql-5.4.x/mysql-tokencleanup.sql

Thanks

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks